# Can I call a controller from a view in different assemblies using Castle Windsor without adding references?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, castle-windsor, .net-assembly

Here is my scenario: I have a master project (MVC4) with models views and controllers. I have another project that was developed by another team. The second (sub) project (MVC4) has models, views and controllers with its views embedded in the assembly.

The assemblies from the sub project are dropped into the master project in a specific folder. 
I cannot recompile the master application to add references to the sub project's assemblies.

Castle Windsor is et to search the folder and successfully finds the classes defined in the assemblies. I have a routine that creates the routes using an XML file definition. The routes use the namespaces option in the route definition and the HTML helpers confirm the routes are available.

Everything seems fine, except that I get an exception when a user clicks a link in the view in the master project which transfers control to the sub project controller. The problem reported is that Castle Windsor cannot find the correct controller to instantiate (although it reports that the module and it's dependencies are constructed ok.

Any clues as to what I might be missing? I know I haven't posted code yet, I am not at the computer with the code. Just looking for ideas on where to look.

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing a little more the best I can say is to put a breakpoint in the master project in a spot directly after you load the container with all your objects.  Then use locals/watch to look at what's in the container.  It might spark something that tells you where your issue is.  Feel free to post code for a more thorough answer.

Comment: seems that problem is in ControllerFactory